# Hide TTY1 login when using no "quiet splash" as GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT

Tags: boot, grub2, login, login-screen, tty

I want to see the boot messages when starting Ubuntu, so I edited `/etc/default/grub` and removed the `quiet splash setting:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
```

But now after those messages and before reaching the greeter/login screen, I am in the TTY1 login prompt for about 3-5 seconds. As this confuses the other people using this machine and is not useful, I would like to disable it and let it rather show a black screen or anything else than the TTY1 login prompt until the GUI greeter is ready.

Note that I want *not* to disable TTY1 login entirely. I just don't want it to automatically show up before the greeter.

Answer (score 0):

open the tty conf in the /etc/init/ directory

comment out those lines in the ttyX.conf files:

```
respawn
exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 ttyX
```

Example to disable tty1:

> sudo -H gedit /etc/init/tty1.conf

Then edit by inserting # in front of the commands

```
#respawn 
#exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
```

Save and Reboot

Comment: That's disabling tty1, op doesn't want that